# Connection events in MassTransit with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I would like to ask is there for MassTransit to notify the client application on RabbitMQ connection state change. I checked IBusObserver, but there is not information when MassTransit disconnects with RabbitMQ.

This is an important function because, in case of disconnection and reconnection, I have to send a message with the current state of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The original answer is about MT 6.**

You need to use the `IReceiveEndpointObserver` instance instead.
Attach the observer when configuring the endpoint:

```
Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    // host and other things
    ...
    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("my_endpoint", ep =>
    {
        // consumers
        ...
        ep.ConnectReceiveEndpointObserver(observer);
    }
}
```

**MT 8 allows registering endpoint observers**

From the [docs](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/observability#receive-endpoint):

```
services.AddReceiveEndpointObserver<ReceiveEndpointObserver>();
```

Comment: link rot has set in for this answer